# How can I detect invalid unicode code points in .NET?

Tags: .net, unicode, invalid-characters

I'm using some PInvoke calls (specifically `GetWindowText()`) and occasionally I get a string with invalid Unicode code points in it (probably due to bugs in the program whose window I'm looking at). When I later try to write that string to XML, I get an exception. So I'd like to check for these invalid characters beforehand and, if possible, remove them from the string.

Unfortunately I cannot find anything in .NET's default functions that would allow me to do that. Did I miss something?

Comment: It looks like the validation rules specified [here](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-7) for Unicode are different from the allowable characters in XML in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML) Wikipedia article.  A brief search didn't turn up any RegEx expressions to validate Unicode v. XML.  Have you looked at [XmlConvert.IsXmlChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.isxmlchar.aspx) and [XmlConvert.VerifyXmlChars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.verifyxmlchars.aspx)?

Comment: Call String.Normalize(), that's likely to trigger the exception.

Comment: @HansPassant - Yes, it does. I just wondered if there was something that doesn't throw an exception. And also I'd like to clean up the string and salvage as much as possible. The result doesn't need to be machine-accurate. It will be for humans to read, so imperfections are acceptable.